# Muliple images from database

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

I want to upload multiple images and save them to the database. But in the Controller action: UploadMorePhotos. I see in files the files that I selected, but if by this line:  `file.SaveAs(path);` it is only saving one Image and then goes to `if (ModelState.IsValid)`. So how to upload all the Images you have selected. Thank You

I have this:

Controller action:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadMorePhotos(UserProfile userProfile, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    //ModelState.Clear();
                }


                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string username = User.Identity.Name;
                    // Get the userprofile
                    UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                    // Update fields
                    user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                    user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

                    return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");
            }

            return View(userProfile);            
        }


 public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
        { 
            byte[] image = db.userProfiles.Where(p => p.Id == id).Select(img => img.Image).FirstOrDefault();
            //var v = // FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(itemId));
           // image = v;
            return File(image,"image/jpeg");            
        }
```

Model:

```
    [DisplayName("Image")]
            [MaxLength]

            public byte[] Image { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Display profile Image")]
            public bool DisplayItem { get; set; }

              [DisplayName("ImageMimeType")]
            public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

              public virtual ICollection<LolaBikePhoto> LolaBikePhotos { get; set; }

public class LolaBikePhoto
    {
        [Key]
        public int PhotoID { get; set; }
        public int UserProfileID { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile userProfile { get; set; }

    }
```

and View:

```
<div id="tabs-3">


           @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadMorePhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
               @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            <div class="form-field">
                <p>Select pictures:</p>
                <div class="upload-container">
                    <div class="upload">
                        <input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple" id="file1" />
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/deleteButton.png")" alt="Remove picture." />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </div>
           }
        </div>
```

I have it now like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadMorePhotos(UserProfile userProfile, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    //ModelState.Clear();
                }


                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string username = User.Identity.Name;
                    // Get the userprofile
                    UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                    // Update fields
                    user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                    user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

                    //return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");
            }

            return View(userProfile);            
        }
```

but still only one image

return View(userProfile); 
            }

```
        return View(userProfile);            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets cut the fat out of your loop:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");
}
```

You are returning from your loop at the end of the first iteration.

If you remove

```
    return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");
```

your loop should complete.

**UPDATE**

> But I want to stay on the tabs-3 after uploading the images

Then replace

```
return View(userProfile);
```

with

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-3");
```

Make sure you return *after your loop is complete*.

Comment: But I want to stay on the tabs-3 after uploading the images

Comment: Then instead of removing it, replace `return View(userProfile)` with it.  As soon as any `return` statement is hit, your method will return.

Comment: But what will be the last return then?

Comment: return View(userProfile); 
            }

            return View(userProfile);            
        }

Comment: two times userProfile?

Comment: @NielsSavant: Only one return statement will ever be executed in your method.  See my updated answer.